# How do I determine the dihedral angle of two (bond-defined) planes?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm not sure if this question would be more appropriate for Chemistry or Physics SE, but if so please forgive me.

I have drawn the following picture; the spheres represent atoms and the lines connecting them represent chemical bonds.

[image]

Another view:

[image]

I would like to determine two dihedral angles:

- the dihedral angle comprised of the vertices **C-G-O-A**.  (Or maybe, although I am not sure, I should state this as the dihedral angle between the bonds **C-G** and **O-A**.)
- the dihedral angle comprised of the vertices **D-A-O-G**.  (Or perhaps this should be the dihedral angle between **D-A** and **O-G**.

**O** is the origin.  The Cartesian coordinates of the vertices are:

- **O** = {0, 0, 0}
- **A** = {-1.2211, -0.705, 0}
- **B** = {1.2211, -0.705, 0}
- **C** = {0, 1.41, 0}
- **D** = {-1.2211, -2.115, 0}
- **E** = {1.2211, -2.115, 0}
- **G** = {0, 0.705, 1.2211}

One problem that I am encountering is that it is not clear to me how a bond between two atoms can define a plane, since I think that a plane is only uniquely defined by three noncollinear points.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_angle) says that the dihedral angle $\varphi_{AB}$ between two planes $A$ and $B$ is simply $\cos \varphi_{AB} = \textbf{n}_A \cdot \textbf{n}_B$ where $\textbf{n}_A$ and $\textbf{n}_B$ are the unit vectors normal to planes $A$ and $B$.  But it is not clear to me how to actually define $A$ and $B$ given only two vertices (i.e., two atoms) defining each plane.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You say that the six points whose coordinates are given all lie on the $x$-$y$-plane, where the $z$-coordinate is zero. But you do not specify the location of **G**. From your diagram, it seems to have $y$-coordinate zero. Without any further information about **G**, I don’t see what can be done.

Comment: @Lubin I messed up and forgot to include the coordinates of **G**. I'm sorry about that. I have now edited my post to include **G** = {0, 0.705, 1.2211}. Thank you!

Comment: For the first angle, it looks like you want the dihedral angle between **AOG** and **OGC**. You can find the normals of the planes by calculating the cross products **OA** $\times$ **OG** and **GC** $\times$ **GO**. The second angle is calculated the same way.

Comment: @Théophile, I think that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @RahulNarain: Done! I just didn't have time to write out the calculations yesterday. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's find the dihedral angle between the planes by taking the dot product of normal unit vectors Three points are needed to determine a plane, so in the chain of bonds **C-G-O-A** we'll take the elements three at a time to get the two planes: **C-G-O** and **G-O-A**.

Let us now calculate unit vectors $\mathbf{n}_{CGO}$ and $\mathbf{n}_{GOA}$ normal to these planes. First note that **C**, **G**, and **O** all have $x$-component $0$, so **C-G-O** lies in the $yz$-plane and we can take $\mathbf{n}_{CGO} = (1,0,0)$. For the other plane, we have:
$$\begin{align}
OG \times OA &= \big((0, 0, 0) - (0, 0.705, 1.2211)\big) \times \big((0, 0, 0) - (-1.2211, -0.705, 0)\big)\\
&=(0, -0.705, -1.2211) \times (1.2211, 0.705, 0)\\
&=(0.8609,-1.4911,0.8609)
\end{align}$$

Before making this a unit vector, let's divide by $0.8609$ to clean things up: this last vector is parallel to $(1,-1.73206,1)$, which I take to be $(1,-\sqrt{3},1)$. Interesting. Shrinking this to a unit vector:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{n}_{GOA} &= \frac{OG \times OA}{|OG \times OA|}\\
&=\frac{(1,-\sqrt{3},1)}{||(1,-\sqrt{3},1)||}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(1,-\sqrt{3},1)\\
\end{align}$$

Finally, the dihedral angle $\phi$ between our two planes satisfies $\cos{\phi} = \mathbf{n}_{CGO} \cdot \mathbf{n}_{GOA} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$. In other words, $\phi = \arccos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}) = 1.1071$, or about $63.43^\circ$.

The dihedral angle for **D-A-O-G** can be calculated the same way.

Comment: Maybe the coefficient should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$, not $\frac{1}{5}$?

Comment: Also, how do you know that $\textbf{n}_{CGO} = (1, 0, 0)$ instead of $(-1, 0, 0)$?  It depends on the order in which you take the cross product.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks, I've fixed the norm; it should indeed be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$. As for the direction of the normal, the nice thing is that it doesn't matter: it suffices to find **a** normal of the plane. If we had used $(-1,0,0)$ instead of $(1,0,0)$, then the final calculation would have given $\phi = 116.56^\circ = -63.43^\circ$. This is the supplementary angle of $63.43^\circ$ and gives the same information.

Comment: Thank you!  But if I look down the **G**-**O** bond (see my edit to my question above), the angle between the planes **CGO** and **GOA** looks *greater* than $90^{\circ}$, not less than $90^{\circ}$.  Why does it seem like $\phi = 116.56^{\circ}$ makes more physical sense?  Maybe I am completely missing the point, though.  Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I have labeled the angle I'm referring to in blue above. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew: Indeed, the angle you're looking for will be $\phi = 116.56^\circ$; you must choose from the calculation that I gave whether to take the smaller or the larger of the two angles. If you have a drawing already, as in your example, it should be clear which to take. Or are you writing a computer program of some kind?

Comment: Thank you! I am indeed writing a computer program (in the language Mathematica). I guess this just means that in general I should find both angles, and then have the computer select the smaller angle, which is always the one that I want.